# Calculate date at another position

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have a date at position A in a Word2016 document and want to have that date plus e.g. 6 month at another given position B in the same document. My idea is to calculate the new date at position B with a reference to the date at position A. How could I do this?

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this. Without knowing your document type & structure, it's impossible to advise the optimum approach. To see how to do this and just about everything else you might want to do with dates in Word using field coding, check out my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, available at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html or: http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party. Do read the document's introductory material.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll take a look into it.